# how to hide browser default tooltip in ie10 and ie11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi when i hover on select box it showing default tool-tip like "You must choose an item from the list"

i am using another plugin for tooltip now it's showing two inline messages one from my tooltip one from browser!

Comment: use an alternative attribute. not the `title=""` attribute. maybe something like `data-title=""`. So make your plugin read the value of `data-title`.

Comment: Hi i did empty title(title="").It's works fine in ie8,9, firefox,chrome but not in ie10, 11(in this two versions i am getting browser default tooltip)

Comment: well ie10 and ie11 should work if it worked for chrome and ff. what plugin are you using? maybe it doesn't support ie10-11. but again it should work if it worked for chrome and ff.

Comment: Even tried without any plugin empty title="" still showing tooltip in ie10, ie11

Comment: really? i just tried it on ie11 and no tooltip is showing for an empty title attribute.

Comment: i tried in simple example it's not showing when i put like this my project i am getting  <select  valid-expiry-date="create" name="expDateMonth" class="select-input" style="width:8em; float:left; margin-right:0.5em;" min="1" max="12" ng-options="month for month in $parent.myForm.months" ng-model="pm.expiryMonth" required error-tooltip  fieldlabel="Expiration Month" pm="pm" title="" onmodal=true>
              <option value="">MM</option>
                            </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making empty title is working fine title=''

Comment: Microsoft must've "fixed" this

Comment: Hi, does giving title="" for input element will work for IE browser.? Because even after giving empty title on hover i am still getting "You must enter valid email address"